# Download file using enyo

Tags: cordova, enyo

I wonder how can I download files through a url, using enyo with phonegap?

Already tried to use the phonegap plugins download, but no success. I tried to use the palmService, but did not find reference to how to insert it in the project.

I used this plugin:
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Downloader

but this plugin didn't work, I have followed the steps to install, but I get the error of undefined for the downloader.

Here is a example:

```
window.plugins.downloader.downloadFile("http://samplepdf.com/sample.pdf", {overwrite: true}, 
  function(res) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(result));
}, function(error) {
    alert(error);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting undefined for the function then the problem is that you didn't get it installed correctly.  Follow the setup procedure again and make sure you rebuild the entire project.  See if that fixes your problem.